# How can I check what day it will be next year on the same date in android

Tags: android, calendar

I want my app to be able to check what will be the day in next year with same date for example

Today is Tuesday August 15 2014

The app needs to know what day will it be on August 15 2015.

And also how can I avoid errors caused by leap years?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the calendar to that date

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(2015,8,15)
```

then get the day

```
cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)
```